# Signing a message digest using BouncyCastle

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

At the moment in C# I'm signing a challenge like this:

```C#
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa;
RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter RSAFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
RSAFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
byte[] SignedHash = RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(paramDataToSign);
```

Then I give the `SignedHash` to Windows, it accepts it and everything is OK. But I need to move this part to Android and there's the problem, that I just can't get the same signed hash value.

In Android I tried to make the signed hash but they differ from the one generated in C#.

```java
Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
signer.initSign(privateKey);
signer.update(paramDataToSign);
signer.sign();
```

In C# - using the following piece of code - I get the same result as in Android, but it is not an option cause then Windows does not accept the signed hash.

```C#
ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withRSA");
signer.Init(true, privateKey);
signer.BlockUpdate(paramDataToSign, 0, paramDataToSign.Length);
signer.GenerateSignature();
```

Here's written that C# PKCS1SignatureFormatter and Java Signature should give the same result, but they do not. http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/dotnet/VerifySig/

What could be the problem?

---

Here are the base 64 (WebSafe) values that I get:

```
Challenge = zHyz12Tk4m151nssYIBWqBCAxhQ

RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter SignedHash = kmu39keplCAV4Qnu22wdprLz4nGSsrVtHbxQ5YMUG7p-0YwReCG4ROIlFvYs4CGfjCiAGFPw4PLrLx7mrlAA6iuhJMkgm_PMTW9alQYTH612hLEUP4EmK0M2kw8CveLcjI3HA08z8bByllIzRyAlM8bcR438vw2uhx_CbgvOOHn8vwBPnvWbFqpi2doYoq2xEuFBRe7eBPrxbMRqEd3ExdQ9c9rYT4ivOJ4pbioyi6D5i5_1crvGwM6nQanMZCmooRYJO65NP3B4wWnvQZpJLRD0U08wWcvyGBFWp188ZovDjnkTQZku6lzmwGXfqQwtBz9uNvLcTbp7cVyt5EyQxw

Signature and ISigner SignedHash = Vt-b5QfGPnSPpZuIB8-H4N1K5hQXpImS4e8k56_HruDSqy3DLsz96QKUrccshjr1z9nTK3Mwvd5yPdyTJOqSUcDQqxV46LPhWQNsubqKxAz97ePpeslIH1gHdnzkh46ixsWqgDrhR7egQtDkU8PPsph1qahCxaVkRYspQBV0jPZ-LK4EjoGGnuWTCihVKjruXJZ2VY8yZ9QRAsHVptr0Nv-mldO2MFK-oEVbtVbHqUPf5So8im3oRSm68OqY4g56bCdFNSbhcFBjrZ1QPjnxiIk43-_5tevafqoOB2D_E_mQHCJwmRg3MrNij6IdAdloCejnhCWzgMHdcG1Ug_Qmig
```

---

EDIT:

So the simplest solution is using Bouncy Castle API:

```java
AsymmetricBlockCipher rsaEngine = new PKCS1Encoding(new RSABlindedEngine());
rsaEngine.init(true, privateKey);

DigestInfo dInfo = new DigestInfo(new AlgorithmIdentifier(X509ObjectIdentifiers.id_SHA1, DERNull.INSTANCE), paramDataToSign);
byte[] digestInfo = dInfo.getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER);

rsaEngine.processBlock(digestInfo, 0, digestInfo.length);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(paramDataToSign);` passes the hash value, while `signer.update(paramDataToSign);` passes the data *before it is hashed*. So it is likely that you have to remove a `MessageDigest` calculation for your Java code for this to work.

Alternatively, if you only have the hash value, you may have a look into the Bouncy Castle lightweight API to find a method that accepts a value that is pre-hashed. This can probably be performed using `new RSADigestSigner(new StaticDigest(paramDataToSign, "SHA-1")).generateSignature()`.

Problem is that `StaticDigest` does not exist, so you'll have to comment here if you really require it. Alternative, mirror the implementation of [`RSADigestSigner`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/bc-java/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/signers/RSADigestSigner.java) but substitute a pre-calculated hash.